# Android emulator network not working on Ubuntu Server

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have the same device configured both on my Mac OS and on Ubuntu Server.
Both are started the same, the only difference is that on the Ubuntu Server I add the -no-window parameter.

On the Mac, I see the following in adb shell

```
generic_x86:/ $ getprop | grep net
[gsm.network.type]: [LTE]
[init.svc.netd]: [running]
[init.svc.ranchu-net]: [stopped]
[net.bt.name]: [Android]
[net.eth0.dns1]: [10.0.2.3]
[net.eth0.gw]: [10.0.2.2]
[net.gprs.local-ip]: [10.0.2.15]
[net.qtaguid_enabled]: [1]
[net.tcp.default_init_rwnd]: [60]
```

While on the Ubuntu Server it's

```
eneric_x86:/ $ getprop | grep net
[init.svc.netd]: [running]
[init.svc.ranchu-net]: [stopped]
[net.bt.name]: [Android]
[net.eth0.dns1]: [10.0.2.3]
[net.eth0.gw]: [10.0.2.2]
[net.gprs.local-ip]: [10.0.2.15]
[net.tcp.default_init_rwnd]: [60]
```

I can't seem to get the Ubuntu Server have the [gsm.network.type]: [LTE] parameter.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to the config.ini solved this

```
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=auto
skin.name=1080x1920
skin.path=_no_skin
skin.path.backup=_no_skin
```